# Vegetative index calculation yields Inf instead of value

Tags: gdal, numpy

I am calculating a the Green Leaf Index (GLI) from an orthomosaic and am somehow getting inf values for certain pixels instead of actual values. When calculated manually, I am getting an expected value. What is the cause for this?

```
#Read raster
fp = [PATH TO GEOTIFF]
ds = gdal.Open(fp)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

r = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
g = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
b = ds.GetRasterBand(3)

r = r.ReadAsArray()
g = g.ReadAsArray()
b = b.ReadAsArray()

# Allow for 0 division in numpy
np.seterr(divide = 'ignore', invalid = 'ignore')

# True for all pixels with value
check = np.logical_or(r > 0, g > 0, b > 0)
# Binary vegetative mask using Excess Green Index
exgMask = np.where(check, 2*(g/(r+g+b)) - r/(r+g+b) - b/(r+g+b) >=0.1, np.nan)
# True for all vegetative pixels
check = exgMask == 1
# Calculate GLI for image
gli = np.where(check, (2*g-r-b)/(2*g+r+b), np.nan)

#Test Calculation   
print(r[1497, 2000])
129
print(g[1497, 2000])
155
print(b[1497, 2000])
73
print(gli[1497, 2000])
inf

R = r[1497, 2000]
G = g[1497, 2000]
B = b[1497, 2000]
print((2*G-R-B)/(2*G+R+B))
0.2109375
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original arrays were in uint8. Converting to uint16 solved the issue.

```
r = r.ReadAsArray().astype(np.uint16)
g = g.ReadAsArray().astype(np.uint16)
b = b.ReadAsArray().astype(np.uint16)
```